# bash + how to print sequence lines in the same line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I created the following find syntax in order to search all files that start with `moon_` and ended with `.xml` and should contain the tag - `<Version>`

here is example

```
find   /main_folder/kits/  -maxdepth 2  -name "moon*" -name "*.xml" -exec grep '<Version>' {} \;    -exec echo {} \;
 
    <Version>1.3.12-dev.137</Version>
/main_folder/kits/A/moon_aaa.xml
    <Version>2.1.1-dev.13</Version>
/main_folder/kits/B/moon_bbb.xml
        <Version>1.0.144</Version>
/main_folder/kits/C/moon_ccc.xml
```

as above its print the **path** and the **version**

but we want to print is better so **path** and **version** will be in the **same line** like the following example

```
find   /main_folder/kits/  -maxdepth 2  -name "moon*" -name "*.xml" -exec grep '<Version>' {} \;    -exec echo {} \; | .........
 
    
/main_folder/kits/A/moon_aaa.xml <Version>1.3.12-dev.137</Version>
/main_folder/kits/B/moon_bbb.xml <Version>2.1.1-dev.13</Version>
/main_folder/kits/C/moon_ccc.xml <Version>1.0.144</Version>
```

what we need to add in our syntax in order to print both in the same line ?

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Needed sample `XML` input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
find /main_folder/kits/ -maxdepth 2 -name 'moon*' -name '.xml' -exec bash -c '
    for xml; do 
        res=$(grep "<Version>" "$xml") && echo "$1 $res"
    done
' bash {} +
```

Or better, instead of `grep`, use :

```
xmllint --xpath '//Version/text()' "$xml"
```